# Open cv and computer vision

Tags: computer-vision

I'm new to computer vision, and I'm looking for a good place to start from, what's better between open cv in python or open cv in c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your programming skills. Here is the summary:

OpenCV is a great tool originally developed in C++ and after a while a Python interface was added. In industry (and also many academic research group) C++ is the popular language for Computer Vision as the nature of data needs efficiency in computation. So starting with python is an easy way to learn Computer Vision and OpenCV capabilities but when you are applying for a job in industry or academia, they most probably need you to get your hands dirty with C++.